# How to capture dvdauthor output to file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to capture dvdauthor's output to a file. 
So far i found this command but it's not working:S

```
dvdauthor -x dvdauthor.xml > output.txt
```

Any kind of idea is really appreciated.

Comment: "Not working" as in empty file, as in error message, as in the computer melts a hole in the floor? Please, we need more info. What do you get without the redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though dvdauthor prints a lot of output to stderr rather than stdout. I don't have this software myself and so can't be sure but I see a lot of this in (what I presume to be) [the source code](https://github.com/ldo/dvdauthor/blob/master/src/dvdauthor.c), which suggests that it's printing informational messages to stderr rather than stdout:

```
fprintf(stderr, "INFO: dvdauthor creating table of contents\n");
```

The > redirect will only redirect stdout to file. To redirect stderr to file, you can use '2>'

Try:

```
dvdauthor -x dvdauthor.xml 2> output.txt
```

You might find the BASH programming introduction useful for more info on redirecting output: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: I will accept your answer as soon the 7 mins left. Thanks again.